# Excel and Sharepoint connectors loosing relationship with files

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to take tasks in planner and put them into excel file on sharepoint.

everyday I want to delete the excel file and dump the whole planner plans and tasks into the excel.

hence created two logic apps
1. one runs at 8:45AM that deletes the existing excel file, copies empty excel template to the location
2. second one pulls the data from planner, filters the fields I need and dumps into excel

the 2nd logic app is loosing the referral of the file.. after the first logic app is done... after 1str logic app is done, I need to manually configure the actions of excel in second logic app to point to appropriate tables..

either I am doing something wrong or this is a nasty bug.. please help.

Comment: Sorry but could you be  little bit more precise (explain the logic, show schema, code..) because it is very difficult to understadn your problem

Comment: Hello Thomas, My logic is as following: 1) Delete excel in sharepoint list. 2) Create a new excel with same name as deleted. 3) query planner plans and Tasks. 4) select needed attributes. 5) dump the data to excel created in step 2.....  as you see this is pretty simple logic flow, but logic app is failing in step 5 saying that the file doesn't exist.. I doubt if the Excel connector looks for the defined file(in its properties) based on name or the GUID.. is there a way to force it to connect to the file based on name

Comment: Can you remove the step 2 and dump the data to a new  excel file directly in one step (on step 5)???

Comment: Recently what I have learned is..  with Excel for business connector is that, I cannot reference files by name.. the file to which I bound the Logic App Action Definition is what I need to stick to otherwise at runtime the action throws exception saying file not found.. looks like the references are taken by File GUID rather than location and name.. which is bad and outrageous implementation, if my understanding of the connectors is good enough